# Is there a way to get the full path (or even just the file name) of a PdfDocument object using itext7 and C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I have a list of PdfDocument objects that were split from one large original PDF file by page number (one doc for each page in the original).

All I want to do is iterate those documents

```
foreach (PdfDocument doc in splitDocuments)
```

And get the file path/doc name of each, but I have not been able to find a property that gives me that basic info. I need to copy the files to a different location based on some info inside the file, but so far I have not been able to get the file path.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there is no unique file name for a `PdfDocument`.

First of all recall that a `PdfDocument` can be created based on a `PdfReader`, a `PdfWriter`, or a `PdfReader` / `PdfWriter` pair. Both the reader and the writer may be file based. Thus, in general it is not clear what you mean by "the" file name, there may be two. But both may also be based on a non-file object, then there is no file name.

If the `PdfWriter` is file based, you can determine the associated file name from the underlying `FileStream`, for a `PdfDocument doc` that is

```
doc.GetWriter().GetOutputStream()
```

For the `PdfReader` the equivalent is not easy (if possible at all): Depending on the options used the file might have been read into a byte array and then forgotten. But even otherwise, i.e. if the reader still is based on the file stream, it is hidden under two or three layers of `internal` or `private` information. Using reflection you can work through those layers but that of course wouldn't be appropriate for production purposes.

Also you mention those `PdfDocument` objects were split from one large original PDF. If that happened by means of the `PdfSplitter` utility class, those documents don't have a `PdfReader` to start with.

Answer (score -1):

Following method will split the file with given page count and return the names of all the new files. It uses itext7 library.

```
        public class PdfHelper
        {
            public List<String> SplitPDF(string sourcePDFpath, int pageCount)
            {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(sourcePDFpath);
                string nameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourcePDFpath);

                PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourcePDFpath));
                PdfSplitterWithFileNames splitter = new PdfSplitterWithFileNames(pdfDoc, info.DirectoryName, nameWithoutExtension);

                IList<PdfDocument> splitDocuments = splitter.SplitByPageCount(pageCount);

                foreach (PdfDocument doc in splitDocuments)
                {
                    doc.Close();
                }
                pdfDoc.Close();

                return splitter.SplitFileNames;
            }

            private class PdfSplitterWithFileNames : PdfSplitter
            {
                private String destFolder;
                private String fileName;
                private int partNumber = 1;

                public List<string> SplitFileNames { get; set; }

                public PdfSplitterWithFileNames(PdfDocument pdfDocument, String destinationFolder, string splitFileName) : base(pdfDocument)
                {
                    this.destFolder = destinationFolder;
                    this.fileName = splitFileName;
                    SplitFileNames = new List<string>();
                }

                protected override PdfWriter GetNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange)
                {
                    string newFileName = $@"{destFolder}\{fileName}_{partNumber++}.pdf";
                    this.SplitFileNames.Add(newFileName);
                    return new PdfWriter(newFileName);
                }
            }
        }

 PdfHelper helper = new PdfHelper();
 List<string> files = helper.SplitPDF(@"<file path>\<filename>.pdf", 500);
```